# Joins vs subqueries in linq?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I have been using linq in combination with entity framework for a few months now and am wondering about subqueries vs joins.

I am using subqueries a lot like this:

```
(from department in
      (from hospital in hospitalRepository.Hospitals
       where hospital.Id == viewModel.DestinationHospitalId
       select hospital.Departments).Single()
 select new { Value = department.Id, Text = department.Name }).ToList();
```

I never really use the join keyword because to me it feel a bit too databasey. I think to do the join I need foreign keys in my domain objects which I don't really like and I feel subqueries are more intuitive. However, I almost always see people use joins in linq, which makes me wonder whether joins are much better or that people are just used to using joins from SQL.

Furthermore, I ran into a problem with my subqueries that when the `Hospitals` ObjectSet doesn't contain a hospital with the id I want. I don't know how to make the subquery return an empty collection. Apparently the default for a list is `null`. Now I use Single and catch the exception, however I would prefer that my query would just return an empty list.

Should I just start using joins? Shouldn't I want my query to return an empty list and handle that case as an exception? Would it have been better if the default for a list would have been an empty one?

Some background: The purpose of this query is to populate a dropdownbox in my view based on a selected value of another dropdownlist. The other dropdownlist could have no selection which would require the first dropdownlist to be empty. So it's not *really* an exception.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would *definitely* start embracing joins if I were you. Fundamentally if you've got two collections, and want to find corresponding rows based on some ID, then that's exactly what a join is for. Don't think about it in terms of databases - think of it in terms of matching.

I'm not entirely sure you need it in this case, mind you... I suspect you'd be fine with:

```
from hospital in hospitalRepository.Hospitals
where hospital.Id == viewModel.DestinationHospitalId
from department in hospital.Departments
select new { Value = department.Id, Text = department.Name }
```

Here, if there are no matching results you *will* end up with an empty list, so that deals with the problem for you. However, you should also be aware of some alternatives to `Single` for other situations:

- `First`
- `FirstOrDefault`
- `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I didn't know I could do that in linq, this looks actually exactly like what I would want to do and what I tried to simulate with the sub-query. Is this considered a join already in linq? Because I thought it would be more like an SQL join where you take the Cartesian product of two sets and then filter on some fields. Furthermore, I'm aware of the alternatives to Single. Anyway, I'm rewriting my queries asap.

Comment: @Matthijs: If you're aware of the alternatives to Single, you should use them instead of catching the exception that Single throws. Look at the SQL generated by the query above - I'm sure it *will* use a join, but that's due to using `hospital.Departments`, which has an implicit join already.

Comment: @Jon: In my query when I use SingleOrDefault I would get a NullArgumentException (or something like that) because `from department in (null) ..`. That's why I used Single and posted this question (my sub-query seemed like it was not the intended way anymore). Then about the join, I was wondering about the term join in linq. You suggested I start using joins more, so I wanted to ensure that the query in your answer is what you meant and not necessarily join as in `from x in X join y in Y on ..`. That's what I mostly see people do when they talk about joins in linq and I prefer not to use that.

Comment: @Matthijs: That's why using the second `from` here (effectively a SelectMany) is the best approach here. As for joins - certainly inner joins and group joins *are* useful in LINQ. You should try to get over your aversion to them, to be honest... why would you not use it when it concisely expresses exactly what you're trying to do (match IDs in distinct entities)?

Comment: @Jon: Ok so you meant the `join` keyword in linq. I think I would use it then if I have two sets and I want to match their items based on some of their properties. However, usually this relation is expressed by navigation properties and then I prefer to use the query from your answer. I just felt that people often use the `join` keyword instead of the navigation property, just because that's the way it is done in SQL (with foreign keys etc.).

Comment: @Matthijs: It depends on the exact situation. Where navigation properties are available, yes, it helps to use them. Where they're not - or where they're inconvenient - joins are useful. I wouldn't explicitly try to avoid them if I were you.

Comment: @Jon: I agree. When I don't have a navigation property available, I will use a join (joins seem nicer than my sub-queries). However I would first wonder about why there is no navigation property (maybe there should be).